# Given an array, how many no. of subsequnces of array such that gcd of numbers in that subsequence will be between a and b

Tags: probability, combinatorics, divisibility, combinations

A sub-sequence can be obtained from the original sequence by deleting $0$ or more integers from the original sequence.

$L \le$ GCD(all numbers in subsequence) $\le R$

number of such sequences.

For example:
say given array has $2$ numbers i.e. $1, 2.$
the possible subsequences are:
$1$
$2$
$1$ 
$2$

Now $gcd(1) = 1$
$gcd(2) = 2$
$gcd(1, 2) = 1$

$a$ and $b$ will be given integers.
say $a = 1$ and $b = 2$
then the answer for : How many no. of subsequences of array have gcd in range $a$ to $b$ i.e. $1$ to $2$, will be **3**

say $a= 1$ and $b= 1$ 
answer will be $2$...

Limit for number of integers in the given array is $50$. Maximum $50$ elements will be there in array.

How can I do it in most efficient way?

Comment: Any chance you can rephrase that in a slightly clearer manner (for future generations to come)?

Comment: @barakmanos updated!!

Comment: Is this and [and your other recent question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130663/how-many-possibilities-of-sequences-are-there-to-have-averages-of-adjecent-two-i) homework or a coding contest? If so, you should mark them as such. If not, some context (for both) of what your trying to solve (context) would be useful.